# How to post an XML file using a Jersey Client?

Tags: java, jersey

```
    final WebResource service = client.resource(UriBuilder.fromUri(WSURI).build());
    service.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    service.accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    final Builder builder = service.header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, HEADER);

    File file = new File("/test.xml");
    builder.entity(file);
    final ClientResponse response = builder.post(ClientResponse.class);
```

I want to send an XML file and receive the response back. The code that I am trying gives 400 BAD request, please could someone help. I am not sure what is going wrong here.

Comment: Please share the URI you are posting to i.e the value of WSURI.

Answer (score 2):

WebResource is immutable - it's methods return a new builder instance. So, the 2nd and 3rd line of your code snippet have no effect, since you ignore their result. Same when you call the `entity()` method. You should do the following instead:

```
final WebResource service = client.resource(UriBuilder.fromUri(WSURI).build());
Builder builder = service.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
builder = builder.accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
builder = builder.header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, HEADER);

File file = new File("/test.xml");
builder = builder.entity(file);
final ClientResponse response = builder.post(ClientResponse.class);
```